# Compare 2objects (JavaScript, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, compare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Is there an easy way to compare 2 separate custom objects for all thier properties if they are the same ?

Example:

```
   var obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: 1
    };

    var obj2 = {
    c: 1,
    b: 1,
    a: 1
    }
```

Comment: How should objects that contain other objects be compared? Recursively, or a shallow compare?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
function compareObject(o1, o2){
    for(var p in o1){
        if(o1[p] !== o2[p]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    for(var p in o2){
        if(o1[p] !== o2[p]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```